# WSO2 UserAdmin API document

Tags: api, wso2

I want to learn about the WSO2 UserAdmin interface, but did not find the relevant document describes this part.

I can get UserAdmin.wsdl, but there is no explanation about the parameters.

Who knows is there a detailed description documentation about UserAdmin interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the User Management functionality for WSO2 Carbon product. It is exposed through following two web services APIs in WSO2 carbon.

1. Remote User Management API: this is recommended to be used by external client applications.
2. UserAdmin service: this is mainly to be used by carbon UI client.

Therefore it is better to use the `RemoteUserStoreManagerService` service. It is available with the  WSO2IS and also can be install with any other WSO2 product.  `RemoteUserStoreManagerService` service contains simple API. You can even identify by looking at the WSDL. I do not think there is a public doc on this. But you can even try this service using SOAPUI tool.  Therefore you can get much idea about the methods.

`https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl`

Also make sure that when accessing AdminServices of carbon from an external client, you need to first authenticate as the admin user. Basically you need to send admin user/password in basic authentication header

Comment: could you please explain a little bit more why is it better to use remote for external apps, or the main differences between RemoteUserStoreManagerService and UserAdmin? Is it simpler, more secure, ...? thx

Comment: There is no issue with security. But i mean `UserAdmin` is called by WSO2 UI... So some method may be dependent with the UI..

Comment: Asela, Can the RemoteUserStoreManagerService.deleteUser be called using a non-Admin account?

Comment: You need have "configure->security" permission